# Telegram telethon messages forwarding bot stopped working

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

starting from yesterday' afternoon my messages forwarding bot stopped to work from grabbing messages from channels, but it seems to work with channels where I am admin. In a few words these code lines (I'm omitting all the previous standard code lines where the client starts)

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def handler(event):
    print(event)
```

are not catching messages if new messages are posted in channels that I follow. Anyone got the same issue?
Do you know if something changed and the channels now can block this kind of events?
Thank you

Comment: Probably I discovered what happened: the message forwarding is blocked trying to grab messages from channels with more than a certain number of followers. In facts my bot works for channel that I follow with less than 1000 followers, otherwise it doesn't grab anything. This is my theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, by upgrading telethon to the last version the issue is solved!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it happened to me too. I tried running GetHistoryRequest() on all channels, and it started working normally again after that.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do it? thank you so much

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue and I unfortunately can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. My case may be different as I am not using a bot account but a regular user to get bot messages.

Updating telethon fixed it a bit.. not entierly though. Now it's working sometimes and sometimes not. Running GetHistoryRequest() in form of iter_messages also didn't help. Not sure whats going on but Telegram must have changed something because it's been working for 2 years and now suddenly there are problems.
Is everything still working fine for you?

Comment: yes, no issues after the telethon upgrade